# What is significant use of ignite-schema-import

Tags: ignite

I am new to Ignite. I have understood about basics of CacheConfiguration and IgniteCache. I have used SqlQuery API by annotating  fields with @QuerySqlField in POJO and by setting setIndexedTypes() on my cache configuration. I got to know about ignite-schema-import which reads schema of the database and creates POJOS and a CacheConfig.java which has queryEntity() and JdbcType(). How can I make use of this two methods(*queryEntity() and JdbcType()*) to configure ignite cache, any code samples are much appreciated.

Actually, I am using JPA to connect to DB. Is there a possibility to tweak ignite-schema-import to make my POJO's JPA compliant. If yes then where should i look into.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of ignite-schema-import utility is to help users migrate from RDBMs to Ignite without need to write a lot code by hand.

As for JPA on generated POJOs - you may submit a Pull Request with this feature (or create your own fork).

Also it may be interesting for you to take a look at [Web Console](https://ignite.apache.org/addons.html#web-console)
It has much more advanced model import from database than Ignite Schema Import Utility.

1. Register on web console.
2. Create sample cluster on "Clusters screen".
3. Go to "Models screen".
4. Click import from database.
5. You will asked to download web-agent. Download, unzip, copy JDBC driver to agent "jdbc-drivers" folder and start it.
6. Return to Web console - and enter JDBC URL + credetials.
7. Select schemas and tables to import and import.
8. Go to "Summary screen" and download "ready to play" project with all configs, java files and pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the web console and it is generating the pojos along with tha CacheConfig.java which has two methods queryEntity() and JdbcType(). How can i make use of this methods. When i tried cacheconfiguration.setEntities method it is taking collection of query entities. And what is the use of jdbctype method.

Comment: sorry its ignite-schema-import  in the above comment not *web console

Comment: `QueryEntity` in another way to configure SQL schema: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries. `JdbcType` is a part of `CacheJdbcPojoStore` configuration, it defines mapping between POJO classes and database tables.